# How to know the File path in servlet

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

If I upload any file in the JSP then how i know the full path of the location where the file is save on servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uploading files using JSP/Servlet, it is suggested to use Apache's Commons FileUpload library: http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Then you can explicitly say where you want to save the uploaded file. For example, you might want to save it into the `c:\my_files` directory. To get started, you can read this [tutorial](http://www.jsptube.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html). For more information, please read FileUpload's [Guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html).